# How to get text from a Review after the "read more..." element

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am pulling review data from a website and when I scrape using CSS Selector and XPATH I only get the text leading up to the "read more..."bit and none after. Is there a way I can scrape the data without clicking the read more... bit?

If not, any ideas how to go about scraping all the text? Do I need to locate the positioning of the read more element, click it (its position will change based on the length of previous text), and then extract using CSS Selector or XPATH?

[Image of said "read more..." element][https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdx49.png][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdx49.png%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the link or HTML you are trying to access

Comment: post full html code pls

Comment: The HTML code of the review text is as follows:                                                     
<div><div dir="ltr" class="_1jlnvra2">This place was visually pleasing space with tall ceilings and nice sunlight. Also a great location. We did have some issues that should be addressed…<button type="button" class="_15rpys7s">read more</button></div></div>